# Change sub-menu wrap in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, how can I add a button or div into all sub-menu li's using wp_nav_menu?

This is my current code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 
  'items_wrap'=>'%3$s', 
  'container' => false
)); ?>
```

This is my desired output:

```
<li class="submenu">
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 
</li>
```

Comment: You will likely have to create your own [Menu Walker Class](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/10/customize-tree-like-data-structures-wordpress-walker-class/).  What you are asking is not actually a trivial task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [Custom Walkers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) are a bit of a pain to work with, until you understand them.

The below custom walker code should get you what you need.  Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
class Custom_Button_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    // We only care about the "end level" part of the menu, where closing </ul> tags are generated
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // This is from WP core code
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        // This line ensures we only add it on the proper level
        $button = (0 == $depth) ? "{$indent}<button type=\"button\">Click Me!</button>\n" : '';
        // This line is modified to include the button markup
        $output .= "{$indent}</ul>\n{$button}";
    }
}
```

To use the custom walker, modify your `wp_nav_menu` call like so:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 
    'items_wrap'     =>'%3$s', 
    'container'      => FALSE,
    'walker'         => new Custom_Button_Walker()
));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Surprised it's so complicated, I am used to TYPO3 where custom menus are pretty easy. 1 question: How do I make it so it will apply to level 1 and 2? I have a 3 tier menu...

Comment: If you want it to apply to all depths, change the line to simply read `$button = "{$indent}<button type=\"button\">Click Me!</button>\n";`